# Bash, zenity progress bar without cancel

Tags: bash, progress-bar, zenity

Currently developing a small bash script, my needs are a progress bar that doesn't 
come with a cancel button. I have been looking into the zenity progress bar, but 
haven't found a way to get rid of the cancel button.

The non-existence of the cancel button is of the essence, since it would completely ruin
the means of the progress bar. I saw a terminal-based progress bar around, but since I use
zenity dialogs for all other cases, I want to use it for the progress bar as well.

Any idéas how to solve my issue? Any other progress bars around, or is it possible to 
get rid of the cancel button?

Any help is very appreciated, thanx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`zenity` supports the `--no-cancel` flag, which removes the cancel button.

For me information see `zenity --help-progress`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
sleep 5|tee >(zenity --progress --pulsate --no-cancel --auto-close --text="Please wait...")
```